# how to enter only numeric values in ipad text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I have a problem restricting a text box to only numeric values.  I used normal methods but it works only in windows, not working in ipod and it allows a user to enter strings and special characters. , if you know how to restrict this on iOS pls help ,

check it....

```
if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 116 ||
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
            ((event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 45) || event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 100 || event.keyCode == 110)) {
                if ((event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 100 || event.keyCode == 110) && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else {return;}
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((event.keyCode >= 219 && event.keyCode <= 222) || (event.keyCode >= 106 && event.keyCode <= 109) || event.keyCode == 111
             || event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 59 || (event.keyCode >= 186 && event.keyCode <= 189) || event.keyCode == 191 || event.keyCode == 192 ||
        event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || (event.keyCode > 105 && event.keycode < 190 )) ){
            /*
             if (checker.apple) {
                // alert('Hh');
                 alert(event.keyCode);
        //$.browser.apple=true;
        event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode <= 48 || event.keyCode >= 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || (event.keyCode > 105 && event.keycode < 190 ))
        event.preventDefault();
    }*/
                //alert(event.keyCode);
                /*event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

Comment: "i used normal methods" doesn't help us know what you've already tried. Please explain what you've already attempted so we don't bother suggesting redundant things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit the user to only type In Numbers:

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if ([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0)
        {
            textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            return NO;
        }

        NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
        if ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0)return YES;

        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: sir its good logic .. please tell me how can i embed this in my code sir ?

Comment: Well put the code I wrote in the ViewController.m and see the part textField.text add your own textfield name..

Comment: this is objective-c.. not javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onkeypress()` when user presses any button and fire checkAlpha() function.

and use following code to detect whether it is a number or a alphabet

```
function checkAlpha() {
x = event.charCode;
if (( x >= 65  && x <=90) || (x >= 97 && x <=122))
{
alert("Yes, it is alphabet");
}
else
{
alert("Sorry, only alphabet allowed");
event.preventDefault();
}
}
```

works fine latest android and desktop please confirm on apple devices and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

please follow this code for enter only numeric value in text box. make sure for these `DELEGATE` methods

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
char *x = (char*)[string UTF8String];
//if(DEBUG_MODE) NSLog(@"char index is %i",x[0]);
if([string isEqualToString:@"0"] || [string isEqualToString:@"1"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"2"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"3"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"4"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"5"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"6"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"7"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"8"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"9"] || x[0]==0 ) {

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 6) ? NO : YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
}
```

Comment: no i am not using x code sir .. i just did in jquery ..to say honestly i searched in internet and embeded it